# cv::connectedComponentsWithStats in OpenCV 3.2.0 sometimes crashes with gcc 6.2

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

Using this simple standalone demo:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // unsigned char data[] = {1, 0, 1}; // crashes
  unsigned char data[] = {1, 1, 0}; // does not crash

  cv::Mat1b testImage = cv::Mat1b(3, 1, data);

  cv::Mat labeledImage;
  cv::Mat stats;
  cv::Mat centroids;
  int neighborhood = 8;

  int componentCount = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(
      testImage, labeledImage, stats, centroids, neighborhood);

  std::cout << "componentCount: " << componentCount << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

With gcc 5.4 it works fine for both 'data' values. With gcc 6.2, it works fine for `{1,1,0}` but dumps this with `data = {1,0,0}`:

```
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00407000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 15214967                           /home/doria/build/Examples/c++/OpenCV/Bug/Bug
00606000-00607000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 15214967                           /home/doria/build/Examples/c++/OpenCV/Bug/Bug
020b2000-0216c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f2608000000-7f2608021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2608021000-7f260c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f260cc1d000-7f260cc24000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10883576                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f260cc24000-7f260ce23000 ---p 00007000 08:01 10883576                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f260ce23000-7f260ce24000 r--p 00006000 08:01 10883576                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f260ce24000-7f260ce25000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 10883576                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
7f260ce25000-7f260ce28000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10883446                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi David! I think I spotted the bug. I'll drop an email to the author of the algorithm to see if he has further insights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm responsible for the bug... sigh.

The problem is that the algorithm works in 2x2 blocks on the image. The maximum number of labels is one per block. Unfortunately if the image has an odd number of row and/or columns the estimate of number of blocks is wrong. So to fix this we should be doing:

```
const size_t Plength = ((img.rows + 1) / 2) * ((img.cols + 1) / 2);
```

<strike>We'll file a pull request to OpenCV for this today. Plus an improved set of tests. By the way we are still waiting for the parallel version (multicore) of the algorithm to be included.</strike>
<strike>We already filed in November a [pull request](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7705) for the parallel version (multicore) of the algorithm which also fixes the bug.</strike>

You can find the fixed version in OpenCV 3.3, since June 2017. Moreover it also includes the parallel version.

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this bug with Visual Studio 2015 (vc14 x64).

The problems seems in line [352 of connectedcomponents.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp#L352):

```
 //A quick and dirty upper bound for the maximimum number of labels.
 const size_t Plength = img.rows*img.cols / 4;
 LabelT *P = (LabelT *)fastMalloc(sizeof(LabelT)* Plength);
```

With your test image, this `PLength` evaluates to `0`:

```
 Plength = (3*1)/4 = 0
```

So `*P` has zero elements.

However, there is this assignement in a few places in the algorithm:

```
 P[lunique] = lunique;
```

and `lunique` has values `>0`. So this causes the heap corruption *sometimes*.

The fix should be to provide a better estimate of the upper bound `Plength`.

Comment: I wish I could give +5 :) This was causing serious headaches today.

Comment: I used both electric fence and valgrind (one at a time) and actually with both it did NOT crash in the case I indicated as "crashes". How else would you track down something like this?

Comment: @David I suppose the visual studio debugger did a pretty good job. The crash was located near the `fastFree` of `P`, so it was clear what to look for